# How can I split rows in a TSV into multiple files based on column values?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm not entirely sure my question is correct. Let me show an example.

I have a TSV file currently that looks like below (where the tab characters are represented by the guillemet mark `»`).

```
SMS Index #»**Protocol**»Address»Type»Subject»Body»Service Center»Status»Read»Date»Locked»Date Sent»Readable Date»Contact Name
0»0»**01234567899**»Received»null»I thought that we were going to »null»»Read»1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC»False»1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC»Dec 31, 1969 7:00:00 PM»(Unknown)
```

I have about 100,000 rows, each has a phone number. I would like to parse through this TSV file, and for each row, copy the row to a new TSV with the phone number. or if that file exists, add the row to it.

So instead of having one very large TSV file consisting of SMS messages from 100's of phone numbers, I'd have 100's of TSV files but each file would only consist of the SMS messages with that corresponding phone number.

How would I go upon doing this?

Comment: "I'd have 100's of TSV files" would seem to imply a relatively small number of different phone numbers (out of the 100,000 rows of data) — is that correct?

Comment: Yes that’s correct.

Comment: In that case, the first part of @Tom's answer should work. Since the number of phone numbers won't be huge, you could create a dictionary mapping already seen phone numbers to opened TSV output files along with their corresponding `csv.writer` objects. Given that, it would be easy to determine whether a phone number has been seen before, and if so, be able to just write another row to it via the existing `csv.writer`'s `writerow()` method. If it's the first time, then a new file could be opened and added as a new entry in the dictionary. At the end, close all the open files in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `csv.reader` in python and set the separator character to tab.  Then for each line open a file with the phone number in append mode and add the line to it using a `csv.writer` (again configured to use tabs) and close it.

If you care about performance, store the rows in a dictionary mapping the phone number to a list of rows and at the end, iterate over the dictionary.